# How do you remove your own app from the android market

Tags: android, google-play

I uploaded an app onto the android market, but i found a bug in it and want to remove it for now. How can I do that?

**Solution as mentioned below**: From the developer console, click the link for your app. Scroll to the bottom, there are 2 buttons - "Unpublish" and "Save". Click "Unpublish"

Comment: could you accept the other answer pls, the accepted answer is outdated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Question and answer are a bit old and it seems the Developer Consoler UI has changed since then, because I don't find the "Unpublish" button at the bottom of the screen.

In fact, it's easier to find now, but it took me a while. From the Developer Console, click in the link for your app. In the header with information about your app, you'll find a link with the text "Unpublish app" (see the screenshot).

[image: Unpublish app link]

Comment: I have had the same issue, am not sure about been easy, why is it greyed out, if you ask me Grey text on Grey background.  when was the last time you seen anything like that. anyway your answer helpful.

Answer (score 13):

You go to market dev console and unpublish it. There is a huge button "Unpublish" at the bottom of the screen with your app

Comment: The only button there is "Upload Application". There is no "Unpublish".... The page I am using is http://market.android.com/publish/Home

Comment: there is one, which is huge and easily visible, at the bottom of the page where u see ur application details. No option is there on the home page though

Comment: I think google changed it from a big easy to see button to a tiny muted link. See rchavarria's answer